# Makefile compile twice different define

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to build two binaries with the same sources, just with a different define.
Basically what I'm doing right now is:

```
OBJ     =       $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

CPPFLAGS_S =    $(INC) -Wall -Wextra -O3 -g -D SERVER
CPPFLAGS_C =    $(INC) -Wall -Wextra -O3 -g -D CLIENT

server: CPPFLAGS= $(CPPFLAGS_S)
client: CPPFLAGS= $(CPPFLAGS_C)

server: $(OBJ)
    g++ $(OBJ) -o $(NAME_S) $(CPPFLAGS_S) $(LIB)

client: $(OBJ)
    g++ $(OBJ) -o $(NAME_C) $(CPPFLAGS_C) $(LIB)

all: server client
```

Obviously it's not working. What it's doing is compiling everything with the SERVER define, and because the .o files are already there, they will be used again to create the client binary, still using the SERVER define. I could use some help.

Comment: Either you need to generate different .o file names for the client and the server, or you need to throw away all of the .o files when compiling the client when the last binary that was compiled was the server. Additionally, the .o files need to (presumably) themselves be compiled with the appropriate flag?

The first case could be done by having different names for client and server .o files, and using substitutions, and the second could be done by having rules on which `client` and `server` depend, which delete all of the .o files depending on the timestamps of the binaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's a pretty fundamental tenet of filesystems that you can only have one file with a given name in the same directory.  There's not much make can do about that!

So you have three choices: you can delete all the object files after you build each target, or you can create differently-named object files for each target, or you can build the objects into different subdirectories for each target.

Personally I prefer the latter, so you'd need to write new rules to explain to make how to create a file in a subdirectory:

```
SERVEROBJ  =       $(SRC:%.cpp=server/%.o)
CLIENTOBJ  =       $(SRC:%.cpp=client/%.o)

CXX        =       g++
CPPFLAGS   =       $(INC)
CXXFLAGS   =       -Wall -Wextra -O3 -g

server: CPPFLAGS += -DSERVER
client: CPPFLAGS += -DCLIENT

all: server client

server client:
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIB)

server: $(SERVEROBJ)
client: $(CLIENTOBJ)

server/%.o: %.cpp
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
client/%.o: %.cpp
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: ^ this! (what I was suggesting, but much more eloquently put!)